# How to Fit an additive linear model data set anorexia package MASS R

Tags: r

Trying to use the package MASS with data set anorexia on R. I am trying to fit an additive linear model using 3 of the predictors I have been given. I have managed to import the data needed using this code

```
library(MASS)
data(anorexia)
head(anorexia)

summary(anorexia)
```

However I'm not sure how to fit an additive linear model the same as examples that I have been shown

Comment: This is an extremely broad question. What are the predictors? How many degrees of freedom do you want for each predictor? Are you trying to use a particular package to fit the model?

Comment: Where are these examples you are looking at?

Comment: let me find the full question for you.

Comment: The data set anorexia in the R package MASS gives the data on weight change for 72 anorexic patients. For each patient it contains the Treat, treatment factor of three levels: ”Cont” (control), ”CBT” (Cognitive Behavioural treatment) and ”FT” (family treatment); Prewt, Weight of patient before study period, in lbs; and Postwt, Weight of patient after study period, in lbs.
Fit an additive linear model for Postwt, using Treat and Prewt as predictors. Do diagnostics and comment on the ﬁt.

Comment: im not sure what its actually asking me to exactly find as other examples i have been given use the anova function and this does not seem to apply here.